# Spring ROO - GenerationType.IDENTITY instead GenerationType.AUTO

Tags: persistence, spring-roo, jpa

Hy,
thers is a option to roo command line to generate _Roo_Jpa_Entity @Id column with @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) instead GenerationType.AUTO ?

I have MySQL database with autoincrement column key and i launch roo reverse enginerr with this command:

database reverse engineer --schema MYSCHEMA --activeRecord false --package MYPACKAGE

In the _Roo_Jpa_Entity generated the column key is with GenerationType.AUTO and I manually modify che Entity to
GenerationType.IDENTITY.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

All Roo commands and its options are described in [Commands reference sections](http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/reference/html/command-index.html). The `database reverse engineer` *currently* doesn't support this option.

If you wish you can contribute to Spring Roo improving this add-on with this feature.

Good luck!